# Is a non-random initialization vector still bad when encrypting short strings?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

We encrypt with AES 256 CBC PKCS5PADDING in Java with the libraries one has to download from Oracle, with Base64 encoding of the resulting byte arrays. I have read that static common initialization vector drastically decreases the security as texts that starts with the chars will looks the same when encrypted. Is this still true for short strings (12 numeric chars)?

I have encrypted a large set and I cannot find any reoccurring substrings in the resulting encrypted strings, even when they start with the same sequence.

Example (plaintext on the left and resulting encrypted string on the right)

- 555555555501 -> U0Mkd0PPloB5iLBy5jM6nw==
- 555555555502 -> NUHWaFs62LMEeyoGA0mGoQ==
- 555555555503 -> X3/XJNd4TzEsMv7V0bXwqg==

Albeit separate from the question, but to preempt some suggestions: we need to be able to do look ups based on plaintext strings and to be able to decrypt. We could do both hashing and encryption, but prefer to avoid it if it does not improve security significantly as it adds complexity.

Answer (score 2):

> I have read that static common initialization vector are bad as one can derive the key from encrypted strings.

I'm curious: where have you read that?

With short (<=16 bytes) plaintext, a random IV effectifely works as a [Salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29), i.e. it causes the ciphertext to differ even if the plain text is the same. This is an important feature in a lot of applications. But you write:

> We need to be able to do look ups based on plaintext strings.

So you want to build some sort of pseudonymization database? If that is a requirement for you, the feature that salt, and in your case random IV adds, is actually one that you specifically don't want. Depending on your other requirements you can probably get away with using a static IV here. But for pseudonymization in general, it is recommended to use a dedicated pseudonym. In your case the data seems to be atomic. But in the general case of, for example, address data, you want to hash the name, the zip code, the city and whatever else your pseudonym is, separately, both to allow more specific queries, and to keep access to and information flow from your data under strict control.

Comment: Q1) I re-watched the video that I made that claim from. I misunderstood it and I have corrected my question. Thanks for pointing that out. Q2) No pseudonymization needed. Many thanks for your prompt answer!